# How to access a json key in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

i have a render problem, in componentDidMount i use axios for a get call, after i assign the json with setstate

the problem is:

when i try to call json's key in render, they are undefined.. bacause componentdidmount works after render..

for example:

```
    export default class ShowDetails extends Component { 
constructor(props) { 
super(props); 
this.accountService=new AccountService(); 
this.state = { 
account:[] 
} 

} 

componentDidMount() { 
this.accountService.getAccount().then(r => this.setState({ account: r.data })); } 

render() { return ( {this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.Formatted} //this is undefined
```

I have alredy tried to move in other place the axios call, but without success

the json:

```
  {
"account": [
    {
        "saldoDisponibileFormatted": "1.664,57",
        "saldoContabileFormatted": "1.341,10",
        "value": "EUR",
        "debit": false,
        "productAlias": null,
        "bank": "bank",
        "iban": "IT31M0326801017052670700860",
        "moviments": [
            {
                "causShort": "Commissioni",
                "import": "1,00",
                "sign": "D"
            },

        ],
        "dateUpdate1": "n/d",
        "dateUpdate2": "4/12/2018"
    },

],
"all": {
    "moneyavailable": {
        "Formatted": "1950,82"
    },
    "moneyavailable2": {
        "Formatted": "31627,35"
    },
    "dateUpdate": "4/12/2018"
}
```

}

Comment: please show your code

Comment: `"all":[ {
    "moneyavailable": {
        "Formatted": "1950,82"
    },
    "moneyavailable2": {
        "Formatted": "31627,35"
    },
    "dateUpdate": "4/12/2018"
}]`

Comment: assuming your JSON is called `data` then `data.all.moneyavailable.Formatted` (note the capital F)

Comment: data.all.moneyavailable.Formatted no works.. is undefined..

Comment: how can you access all other data and not all data?

Comment: Please add a live exmpale of what you are trying to do

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/of86j9u4/ try this?

Comment: this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.formatted, the json is in the state

Comment: What is the name of the property in the state where the json is assigned to?

Comment: response => this.setState({ account: response.data.all}) axios call get

Comment: So the state property `account` is where your json is populated to?

Comment: Yes, the initial state is: account: []

Comment: Please post the code of the component having the state in your question.

Comment: this.state = {
        account: []

Comment: componentDidMount() {
 
    this.contiService.geAccount().then(r => this.setState({ account: r.data.all }));
  }

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to access asynchronous data here. Try console logging `this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.Formatted` in the state callback and see if that returns the property.

Comment: As I requested above, can you please post the component with the state in your question too.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'moneyavailable' of undefined

Comment: Please post the component with the state so I can check if the problem is async related. The json above is fine and so is the way I called it too.

Comment: export default class ShowDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.accountService=new AccountService();
 
    this.state = {
     
        account:[]
    }
    
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  
    this.accountService.getAccount().then(r => this.setState({ account: r.data }));
  }

Comment: render() {
    return ( {this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.Formatted}

Comment: It's a rendering problem

Comment: Who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

To access properties on your object you can do this:

```js
const data = {
    "account": [
        {
            "saldoDisponibileFormatted": "1.664,57",
            "saldoContabileFormatted": "1.341,10",
            "value": "EUR",
            "debit": false,
            "productAlias": null,
            "bank": "bank",
            "iban": "IT31M0326801017052670700860",
            "moviments": [
                {
                    "causShort": "Commissioni",
                    "import": "1,00",
                    "sign": "D"
                },

            ],
            "dateUpdate1": "n/d",
            "dateUpdate2": "4/12/2018"
        },

    ],
    "all": {
        "moneyavailable": {
            "Formatted": "1950,82"
        },
        "moneyavailable2": {
            "Formatted": "31627,35"
        },
        "dateUpdate": "4/12/2018"
    }
}

console.log(data.all) // for the all key
console.log(data.account) // for the account key
console.log(data.all.moneyavailable.Formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json is assigned to a property in your state called `jsonData`, you can access that property like this:

```
this.state.jsonData.all.moneyavailable.Formatted
```

---

Check the snippet below:

```js
var jsonData = {
  "account": [
      {
          "saldoDisponibileFormatted": "1.664,57",
          "saldoContabileFormatted": "1.341,10",
          "value": "EUR",
          "debit": false,
          "productAlias": null,
          "bank": "bank",
          "iban": "IT31M0326801017052670700860",
          "moviments": [
              {
                  "causShort": "Commissioni",
                  "import": "1,00",
                  "sign": "D"
              },

          ],
          "dateUpdate1": "n/d",
          "dateUpdate2": "4/12/2018"
      },

  ],
  "all": {
      "moneyavailable": {
          "Formatted": "1950,82"
      },
      "moneyavailable2": {
          "Formatted": "31627,35"
      },
      "dateUpdate": "4/12/2018"
  }
}

console.log(jsonData.all.moneyavailable.Formatted);
alert(jsonData.all.moneyavailable.Formatted);
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/rh8d0aqz/6/

Answer (score -1):

Just store json in one variable.

```
var data = { ... json};
console.log(data.all.moneyavailable);
```